# database design - best practices when using relations to avoid problems?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

i am writing this message to have an advice on "how to design my databases".

i'm not a developer, just have some basic knowledge to code my own websites, and design some very basic DRMs.

my "problem" is the following :

i usually create my tables (regardless of the database i'm using, MySQL, Oracle etc.) based on the same basic principles (without using foreign keys), and at the end, my programs always have huge queries in them, with what i call "soft" relations (as seen in tutorials..) such as :

```
select
 a.field1
 a.field2
 b.field3
 c.field4
 d.field5
 d.field16
 x.fieldN
from
 table1 a,
 table2 b,
 table3 c,
 table4 d,
 tableN x
where
 table1.id = table2.user_id
 and table1.thingid = table3.thing_id
 and table1.group_id = table3.group_id
 and table2.id = table4.id
 and so.on
 and so.on
 and so.on
 and so.on
 and so.on
```

the problems are multiple :

1. i have huge queries, with tons of relations using dots, hard to manage and read
2. it's a pain to maintain
3. if i change any column name or field name i have to adapt my code
4. deleting some data screw up the relations (i know i have to use constraints to avoid that)

so my questions are :

1. is it a best practice to do that ?
2. should i use foreign keys instead ? and what is the best way to do it ?
3. should i use any other method ? and/or do you know any good book i could buy to learn these "database design best practices".

thank you
regards

PS : another quick question, when coding,should i keep the queries in the PHP pages themselves, or is it a best practice to isolate the queries by putting them all in a config file or something ? thanks ! (i'm using PHP)

Comment: Your queries would probably be much more readable and maintainable if you used modern join syntax with join conditions on ON clauses instead of that archaic comma notation where you toss all your join conditions into one WHERE in no particular order.

Comment: I Agree with @Uueerdo, and furthermore it's mandatory for you to read about Database Normalization before embarking in the construction of a data repository. I'm sure that 70% (if not more) of a system efficiency (and by this I mean even program code maintenance, and not just data retrieval) comes from a well planed relational schema. So anything that you can read on the subject will come handy. Other than that, I believe this ain't the place for asking for such directions, this is a site that focuses on punctual issues with code developing, and not a forum to discuss implementation technics.

Comment: As for your last question, take a look at [MVC Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). You can certainly find quite a few tutorials and / or frameworks to implement your application using MVC.

Comment: Your example doesn't tell us anything--it has the form of very simple queries with no problems. You need to read some textbooks(s) on information modeling & database design. Please edit to give us some example base tables and queries and tell us what rows go in each table in a given business situation and what databse states can ever arise. Then we can maybe say, here's a problem that is like problems that you need to read books to avoid. PS Telling us you call some queries soft tells us nothing. Adding quotes tells us you *know* you're telling us nothing but are telling us anyway.

Comment: PS 1. You don't need know or declare PKs/UNIQUEs or FKs or other constraints to query or update. You only need to know what rows go in each table in a given business situation. Constraints are for integrity; they allow the DBMS to reject update attempts to states that can never arise. 2. Are you by any chance (mis)using EAV?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena MVC is a UI decomposition pattern and has nothing to do with data modeling. You're probably thinking of network data modeling, which is the data model behind object-relational mappers which are used in many frameworks which call themselves MVC frameworks. However, I would advise the OP to avoid ORMs and learn the relational model of data instead.

Comment: SQL was invented nearly half a century ago.  Textbooks and third party software that try to impose OO, modeling, etc, on top of SQL tends to obfuscate the limited number of things that can actually be done in SQL.

Comment: @philipxy - "Constraints" are for integrity; "Indexes" are for performance.  PKs, UNIQUEs, and FKs (at least in MySQL) create both Constraints and Indexes.  Plain `INDEX` creates just an index.

Comment: @RickJames I agree. (The SQLstandard has nothing to say about indexes, they are vendor-/implementation-specific.) It is not clear to me why I made that PS. I think it was to say that logical design designs table meanings (while  constraints are determined by them). The question doesn't explicitly mention physical design (perfomance including indexes).

Answer (score 2):

(In MySQL...)

"Tons of joins" will work (up to a limit of 61), but it is symptomatic of a bad schema design.  It is rare to see more than 4 tables joined, except in an EAV schema (which is problematical).

A `FOREIGN KEY` generates an `INDEX`.  An `INDEX` is needed for performance of a `JOIN`.  Without an index, the second table (whichever one that is) needs to be fully scanned; with a suitable index, the lookup is 'immediate'.

Sometimes a ton of joins comes from a beginner "over-normalizing".

Would you care to further describe your application and schema; then we can teach-by-example instead of teach-by-hand-waving.